# Program not entering while loop with only condition being 1

Tags: c++, c, while-loop, webserver

Hi I am writing a simple web server in C that will just handle simple get and post requests sent from a browser. I am not that familiar with C so debugging has been painful but I have gotten it to compile but continually I am getting a err_connection_reset response from my browser when trying to view webpage. I have narrowed it down to not entering the main loop that used to listen on the open socket but it will not enter it, here is my main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("in main");
    int portno;                 // port number passed as parameter
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);     // convert port num to integer

    if (portno < 24)
    {
        portno = portno + 2000;
    }
    else if ((portno > 24) && (portno < 1024))
    {
        portno = portno + 1000;
    }
    else
    {
        ;
    }

    // Signal SigCatcher to eliminate zombies
    // a zombie is a thread that has ended but must
    // be terminated to remove it
    signal(SIGCHLD, SigCatcher);

    int sockfd;                 // socket for binding
    int newsockfd;              // socket for this connection
    int clilen;                 // size of client address
    int pid;                    // PID of created thread
    // socket structures used in socket creation
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

    // Create a socket for the connection
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        error("ERROR opening socket\n");
    }

    // bzero zeroes buffers, zero the server address buffer
    bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    // set up the server address
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    // bind to the socket
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR on binding. Did you forget to kill the last server?\n");

    listen(sockfd, 5);          // Listen on socket
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);  // size of client address

    while (1)
    {                           // loop forever listening on socket
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, (socklen_t *) & clilen);

        if (newsockfd < 0)
            error("ERROR on accept");

        // Server waits on accept waiting for client request
        // When request received fork a new thread to handle it
        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0)
            error("ERROR on fork\n");

        if (pid == 0)
        {                       // request received
            close(sockfd);
            // Create thread and socket to handle
            httpthread(newsockfd, cli_addr);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
            close(newsockfd);
    }                           /* end of while */

    return 0;                   /* we never get here */
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not entering the loop? How are you deciding that? Did you check your logs for the `error` messages? Or put in more trace statements before the loop to see where it's going.

Comment: the loop may be optimized away by the compiler.  Try recompiling with optimization turned off and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky on what basis would the compiler optimize out the loop?

Comment: There are not errors when I check the logs, I have run in gdb and not been able to find anything either. What I dont get is why it would not enter the loop since the condition is just simply 1 and everything that I have seen says that should work fine for a infinite loop condition.

Comment: @Dmitry Beransky I have tried that and no success either

Comment: Since `while(1)` is neither extremely obscure, nor particularly hard (and should not optimize out unless it's entirely trivial to remove the entire loop - e.g. `while(1) break;` may get optimised out. Unless of course, you are using a compiler written by a beginner on compiler writing.

Comment: @user2793027 how do you know it's not entering the loop? I don't see anything that would obviously fail prior to the loop, but there could be some subtle failure mode somewhere. The best thing to do, as I mentioned, is to trace it through, e.g., using some print statement or debugger.

Comment: Have you configure your socket to be non-blocking? Are you sure you have incoming connection? try printf before and after accept to see if it ever returns. Since it's right at the beginning of the loop, it might seem to you that you don't enter when you're in fact entering and getting into an infinite wait inside accept right away

Comment: How would you set it to be non-blocking? I know that it returns a value after the accept now. But not I am having an issue where it will not enter the function httpthread(newsockfd, cli_addr) I know that there is a value for newsockfd and I assume that cli_addr has a value as well but dont know how to check to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

The loop executes exactly once, and then the program terminates because you call exit(0) in the parent process. When you call exit, the entire process dies, including active threads. This includes the thread that is created by calling httpthread(newsockfd, cli_addr).

Besides, the child process is closing the socket. Check that you really want to do this, and do not terminate the program inside the parent process.

Comment: Humm I have checked to see that it was actually entering the loop, with just a simple printf once it enters the loop, however that printf is never displayed. So I dont think that it is just entering and executing once

Comment: did you flush stdout?

Comment: I now know it enters the loop and gets all the way down to httpthread(newsockfd, cli_addr) how ever it does not enter the httpthread function, I know there is a value for newsockfd but since cli_addr is a struct I cannot tell if there is a value in there as well.

Comment: Have you tried debugging with a proper tool, like gdb? Using prints can be ineffective to debug code like this.